# Simultaneous accesses to <Address>, but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: swift4, shared-memory

I want to specify the property which is an array for manipulation in the function `myFunc`, but I am getting this error. Here is my code sketch.

```
self.data = MyObject()

func myFunc(x: inout [Int], y: inout [[Int]]) {
    //manipulation code to x and y
}

myFunc(x: &self.data.array1, y: &self.data.array2)
myFunc(x: &self.data.array3, y: &self.data.array4)
```

Any idea how to make it work? Is there a better pattern I should use for this use case? Thx for advance!

Comment: What is self and what is data?

Comment: `data` is the instance of a Custom class

Answer (score 4):

Very thoroughly explained in the Swift documentation:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/memorysafety/

Basically you are threatening to mutate / write to the same object in two different ways simultaneously. That’s incoherent and if the compiler doesn’t stop you the runtime will.

Comment: The problem might be that Swift can’t be sure these are not the same array.

Comment: So how to implement this use case?

Comment: Don’t use inout.

Comment: So my mistake was: I was using inout with class instance. I got stuck with this issue for this problem in swift: linked list reversal by groups of size k.